# How to handle 'display name' for add_object_type?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx's `add_object_type` to create a custom object `confval` for configuration file values:

```
add_object_type('confval', 'confval', objname='configuration value', indextemplate='pair: %s; configuration value')`
```

However I have multiple configuration files and they could have the same value.

Consider:

```
..confval:  filepath

    Description filepath in configuration file foo.cfg
```

And

```
..confval:  filepath

    Description filepath in configuration file bar.cfg
```

I now have two filepath values.  I could make them unique by changing their names to `foo-filename` and `bar-filename` but that changes the text that is presented to the user.

How can I generate unique index names for the values while maintaining the text that the user sees?

My current idea is to add an `index` option:

```
..confval:  filepath
    :index: foo-filepath

    Description filepath in configuration file foo.cfg
```

But that would require creating a directive class.  Can I do something with `add_object_type`?